# How to overload << operator of non-type parameter template alias?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operators, iostream

I wanna overload `operator<<` of a non-type parameter template alias.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

template<int N>
using centroids = std::vector<typename std::bitset<N>>;

template<int N>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & o, centroids<N> const & c)
{
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    centroids<16> c;
    std::cout << c << std::endl; // <-- fails as overloaded
    return 0                     //     operator<< is not found
}
```

Compiling fails as overloaded operator<< is not found.

How to overload << operator of this non-type parameter template alias?

Comment: You really do not need to.  If you provide a function to output each element of the vector that is all you need.  `std::bitset` provides its own `operator <<` for stream output.

Comment: `std::bitset` is defined for `size_t`, not for `int`. Your code compiles if you replace `int` by `size_t` in template argument definition - Don't ask me why thought ;)

Comment: Thanks Holt. That's the solution.